# How do i get the state of a pair of RadioButtons, in a RadioGroup, in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, radio-group

I have a **list-view** with a custom list row. In each **list-view's** row, there is a **Radio-group** with 2 **Radio-buttons**.

I need to know the state of the **RadioButtons**, for each row of the **ListView** (checked or not), dynamically, as the user click on one of the **RadioGroup's** options.

My main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff3f2f2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/titulo_cabecalho"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="36sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to top -->

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectEscola"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chamada"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#c0000000" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:background="@drawable/border" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listChamada"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                    android:padding="2dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/border2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listEdit"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/list" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:src="@drawable/boy" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomealuno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/matriculaaluno"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Nome:"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/matriculaaluno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nomealuno"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Matrícula: "
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroupChamada"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobuttonPresente"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"
                android:paddingLeft="22dip"
                android:text="Presente" >
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobuttonAusente"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:button="@null"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"
                android:paddingLeft="22dip"
                android:text="Ausente" >
            </RadioButton>
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I populate the ListView:

1 - Code to put the data received from server received in Json format, in arrays and hashmap (I use the arrays to have a reference to the data present in the ListView and hashmap to populate it) :

```
if (success2 == 1) // If data from server was sent without errors
{
    int lenght = jArray.length();
    optionsMatriculas = new ArrayList<String>(lenght);
    optionsNomesAlunos = new ArrayList<String>(lenght);
    optionsSexoAlunos = new ArrayList<String>(lenght);

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            resultDataCodigoAluno = oneObject.getString("cdaluno");
            resultDataNomes = oneObject.getString("nome");
            resultDataSexo = oneObject.getString("sexo");

            optionsMatriculas.add(resultDataCodigoAluno);
            optionsNomesAlunos.add(resultDataNomes);
            optionsSexoAlunos.add(resultDataSexo);

            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

            if (resultDataSexo.equals("M"))
            {
                hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.boy));
            }
            else
            {
                hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.girl));
            }

            hm.put("matricula", resultDataCodigoAluno);
            hm.put("nome", resultDataNomes);

            alunosLista.add(hm);

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing JSon: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    Message msg = myHandler.obtainMessage();
    myHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

This is the code to populate the listview:

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), alunosLista, R.layout.list_row, from, to);
            listaChamada.setAdapter(adapter);

            int lenght = adapter.getCount();
            int totalHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
            {
                View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listaChamada);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listaChamada.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + 4 + (listaChamada.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
            listaChamada.setLayoutParams(params);
            listaChamada.requestLayout();                   
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erro no ListView: " + e.toString());
        }
    }//handleMessage 
};//myHandler
```

I have searched, in Google, but still no luck.
Thanks for any clue about this.

Comment: Please add your listview related creation and binding code for each row, as well as custom adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Android adapters is not that simple. `SimpleAdapter` can be applied only in some very simple/trivial cases. Usually, it's preferred to create own `BaseAdapter`: it gives much more flexibility and doesn't require lot of code.
In your case I would suggest to use smth like the following (You failed to provide any information about that is `from` and `to` in your `SimpleAdapter` constructor, so I guessed):

Main part is proper adapter, which should store selected radio button id and provide it back to the activity/receiver.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListAdapter.RadioButtonsListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mAlunosLista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ListView listaChamada = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada);
        // Fill list with data
        Random sexGen = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            addTextData(sexGen.nextBoolean() ? "M" : "F", Integer.toString(i + 100), "Name" + i + " Surname" + i);
        }

        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mAlunosLista);

        listaChamada.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final MyListAdapter adapter = (MyListAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada)).getAdapter();

        adapter.setRadioListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        final MyListAdapter adapter = (MyListAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada)).getAdapter();

        adapter.setRadioListener(null);
    }

    /**
     * Adds test data to adapter array
     */
    private void addTextData(final String resultDataSexo, final String resultDataCodigoAluno, final String resultDataNomes) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // NOTE: not sure why you convert ids to strings
        if (resultDataSexo.equals("M")) {
            hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.boy));
        } else {
            hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.girl));
        }

        hm.put("matricula", resultDataCodigoAluno);
        hm.put("nome", resultDataNomes);

        mAlunosLista.add(hm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final int position, final HashMap<String, String> itemData, final int clickedId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked item at " + position + ", checked id: " + (clickedId == R.id.radiobuttonPresente ? "Presente" : "Ausente"));
    }
}
```

Below other files I've changed to have compilable example (please refer [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask questions about code questions body).

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--suppress AndroidLintUselessParent, AndroidLintContentDescription -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff3f2f2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="36sp" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer aligned to top

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
    -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectEscola"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chamada"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#c0000000" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listChamada"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:padding="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listEdit"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomealuno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/matriculaaluno"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Nome:"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/matriculaaluno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/nomealuno"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Matrícula: "
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroupChamada"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiobuttonPresente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="22dip"
            android:text="Presente" />
        <!--android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"-->

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiobuttonAusente"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="22dip"
            android:text="Ausente" />
        <!--android:drawableRight="@drawable/btn_check"-->
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListAdapter.RadioButtonsListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mAlunosLista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ListView listaChamada = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada);
        // Fill list with data
        Random sexGen = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            addTextData(sexGen.nextBoolean() ? "M" : "F", Integer.toString(i + 100), "Name" + i + " Surname" + i);
        }

        final MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mAlunosLista);

        listaChamada.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final MyListAdapter adapter = (MyListAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada)).getAdapter();

        adapter.setRadioListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        final MyListAdapter adapter = (MyListAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listChamada)).getAdapter();

        adapter.setRadioListener(null);
    }

    /**
     * Adds test data to adapter array
     */
    private void addTextData(final String resultDataSexo, final String resultDataCodigoAluno, final String resultDataNomes) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // NOTE: not sure why you convert ids to strings
        if (resultDataSexo.equals("M")) {
            hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.boy));
        } else {
            hm.put("sexo", Integer.toString(R.drawable.girl));
        }

        hm.put("matricula", resultDataCodigoAluno);
        hm.put("nome", resultDataNomes);

        mAlunosLista.add(hm);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(final int position, final HashMap<String, String> itemData, final int clickedId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked item at " + position + ", checked id: " + (clickedId == R.id.radiobuttonPresente ? "Presente" : "Ausente"));
```

}
}

PS Also, it looks like You're trying to make some hack to `ListView`. I have no idea why do You need it here, but it's better to avoid until completely necessary.